# JavaScript function for 3 different timezones

Tags: javascript, timezone

I have questions regarding my below code with clocks. How can I adjust the function for three different time zones? Should I work with Class in this case?

```js
const secondHand = document.getElementById("second_hand");
const minsHand = document.getElementById("min_hand");
const hourHand = document.getElementById("hour_hand");

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date(); 

  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = (seconds / 60) * 360 + 90; 
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;

  const mins = now.getMinutes();
  const minsDegrees = (mins / 60) * 360 + (seconds / 60) * 6 + 90;
  minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;

  const hour = now.getHours();
  const hourDegrees = (hour / 12) * 360 + (mins / 60) * 30 + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
}
setInterval(setDate, 1000);
setDate();
```

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser (unless you're using node), so it gets whatever the system time is set to.

Answer (score 0):

The date constructor has the `.toLocaleString()` function, which will return the current date / time of a spesific time zone (given you only use modern web browsers / node versions).

For example:
`let newYorkTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})`

see this question for more info: [How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone)